# How do I manually refactor a python project?

Tags: python, package, directory-structure

As I'm learning more and more about how not to structure a coding project, I'm realizing I have to move a lot of things around to get them in the right places.

For example, I have a "practice data science" project that I'm just dumping all sorts of unrelated code into. My directory looks like this:

```
 - PyCharm Projects
     - data-science-at-home
         - birth_names.py
         - birthplots.py
         - genedata.py
         - etc.
```

Now, I am learning about separating your code into "packages" that are related modules (.py files, right?).

So in my IDE (PyCharm) I created a new packages and then move refactored my .py files to them:

```
 - PyCharm Projects
     - data-science-at-home
         - birth-names
             - birth_names.py
             - birthplots.py
         - package_genestuff
             - genedata.py
```

So what I found is that all of my code is still compiling and running as expected, but at the top of my graphingutility.py file, where I `import birthnames as bn`, I am getting a `no module named birthnames` error. For some reason, everything is compiling and the module that supposedly does not exist is being used repeatedly, but that error popup is really annoying.

I noticed that move refactor only works about half the time, and seems to cause a lot of problems when it does work. Perhaps doing this kind of thing manually would be better, but I don't understand the inner workings of all the xml, config and git files that seem to get changed every time I twitch a finger... What is the appropriate way to get this done?

**EDIT:** As requested, the actual code:

```
import birth_names as bn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def myPlotter(ax, data1, data2, param_dict):
    out = ax.plot(data1, data2, **param_dict)
    return out


def plotRankAndScores(name, gender):

    files = bn.getPaths()
    print(files)
    x1, y1 = bn.getAllRanks(name, gender, files)
    x2, y2 = bn.getAllScores(name, gender, files)
    ave = bn.getAverageRank(name, gender, select=False, filez=files)

    # fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1)
    # myPlotter(ax1, x1, y1, {'linestyle': '-.', 'color': 'red'})
    # myPlotter(ax2, x2, y2, {'linestyle': '--'})

    fig2, (ax3, ax4) = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex='all', figsize=(10, 10))
    plt.xlabel("Year")
    ax3.plot(x1, y1, 'b')
    ax3.set_ylabel("Rank")
    ax3.axhline(y1.mean(), label='average = {}'.format(ave), linestyle='--', color='red')
    ax3.legend()
    ax4.plot(x2, y2, 'b')
    ax4.set_ylabel("Number of Births")
    ax4.axhline(y2.mean(), label='average = {}'.format(y2.mean()), linestyle='--', color='red')
    ax4.legend()
    plt.suptitle("Name Rank and Number of Births by Year")
    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    plotRankAndScores("Wesley", "M")
```

Comment: You will need to show us some code and error messages for us to be able to help you. You might just have a path wrong. Where do you import `birthnames` from?

Comment: @TammoHeeren  What do you mean? I showed the exact hierarchy in the question. The two files are sitting side by side in the same package/folder, as illustrated above.

Comment: What is your python path?  Show us the output of `print(sys.path)`.

Comment: To import a module, either it needs to be in the current directory, or its parent directory needs to be in `sys.path`.

Comment: @JohnGordon, well the two files are side by side in the same directory. So maybe the sys.path thing? What's that?

Comment: Your file is named `birthnames.py` but your are importing `birth_names`. Both need to be named the same (minus the `.py` in the import)

Comment: @TammoHeeren I was being lazy in the typing of the question. The actual file names match. That's poor form on my part, I will fix my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the top line to this:
`from . import birth_names as bn`

Explanation:
In english, the above line means: from the directory in which this script is located, import the file 'birth_names' with the name 'bn'

The `.` indicates the local directory.

Comment: `__init__.py` is only needed for Python 2.  in Python 3, you can have modules without it.

Comment: Got it. Would you post the code from the graphingutility.py file?

Comment: As posted, the code is `import birth_names as bn`.  But the actual module name is `birthnames`, not `birth_names`.

Comment: @JohnGordon I'm sorry, I didn't expect people to want actual code, so I was lazy with my question.The actual file names do match. That is very poor form on my part, and I have updated the question to reflect that the import names and the file names actually do match.

Comment: Updated answer! I have replicated your setup and the import is working for me.

Comment: @TD1 Perfect, that resolved it! Any clue as to why this is the right approach?

Comment: Actually, bad news... The red squiggly lines went away on the import statement, but it actually will not compile and run. How odd that it works with the error, but won't when there are none. I suppose I'll just live with the red squiggles as long as it is working.